# Change Collection View Cell background with navigation bar button Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I hope someone can help you on this coding issue. I want to change my collection view cell background color with a navigation bar button and this is my bar button selector code:

```
func handleBrightnessChanged() {
   let readingCell = ReadingsDisplayCell()
   readingCell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

However, the button doesn't do anything when I click on it. Can you please help me? Below is my UICollectionViewCell class:

```
class ReadingsDisplayCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("fatal error in Daily cell")
    }

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: At run time, is the collectionView cell's background color gray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new cell and setting its background color, which has no effect on the existing cells. To change the color of your cells, follow these steps.

First, create a property to keep track of the cell color.

```
var currentBackgroundColor = UIColor.gray
```

In your `handleBrightnessChanged` function, set this property to your new value.

```
func handleBrightnessChanged() {
    currentBackgroundColor = .red
}
```

Next, set the background color of your cells in your `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myID", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = currentBackgroundColor
    return cell
}
```

To have this change take effect when the button is pressed, reload the collection view's data when the button is pressed.

```
func handleBrightnessChanged() {
    currentBackgroundColor = .red
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I'm looking for.